# MatPlotLib Scatter not working Inside Function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, data-science, scatter-plot

I am a beginner in Python. I have been trying my hands on MatPlotLib to compare the stats of soccer players in FIFA 20. Basically the problem I'm facing is:

```
def make_graph(value1, value2, namevalue, label1, label2):
    print(value1, value2, namevalue)
    plt.scatter(value1, value2)
    plt.xlabel(label1)
    plt.ylabel(label2)
    for i in range(len(namevalue)):
        plt.text(value1[i] + 0.3, value2[i] + 0.3, namevalue[i], fontdict=dict(color='red', size=10), bbox=dict(facecolor = 'yellow', alpha=0.5))

    plt.xlim(min(value1) - 5, max(value2) + 5)
    plt.ylim(min(value1) - 5, max(value2) + 5)
    plt.show()





def Test():

    df = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    data = df.sheet_by_index(0)

    data.cell_value(0,0)
    name = []
    pace = []
    shoot = []
    for i in range(1, 450):
        #print(data.cell_value(i, 3))
        buff = str(data.cell_value(i,2)).strip()
        if buff == "LM" or buff == "RM":
            pacebuffer = int(data.cell_value(i, 4))
            shootbuffer = int(data.cell_value(i, 5))
            if pacebuffer >= 90:
                name.append(data.cell_value(i, 3).strip("\n"))
                pace.append(pacebuffer)
                shoot.append(shootbuffer)

    #print(name)
    make_graph(pace, shoot, name, "Pace", "Shoot")
```

The particular code is showing me an empty graph.
**BUT**
When I write the same piece of code inside `Test()` which I wrote inside `make_graph()` , it gives me the desired output.
But in this way I have to rewrite that plotting thing every time I write some other functions and that's really a problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is not reproducible with random data for pace, shoot, name. Any specific environment you use (PyCharm, Spyder, Anaconda) that might interfere? And are you sure that the variables provided to the function contain values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your x and y lims :

```
plt.xlim(min(value1) - 5, max(value2) + 5)
plt.ylim(min(value1) - 5, max(value2) + 5)
```

You should change to :

```
plt.xlim(min(value1) - 5, max(value1) + 5)
plt.ylim(min(value2) - 5, max(value2) + 5)
```

Technically your plt.scatter was working but then your x and y lims meant that you couldn't see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really a rookie mistake.